# 'wx/wx.h' file not found in eclipse cdt project with codelite's latest wxwidget version

Tags: eclipse, wxwidgets

My wxwidget(3.10 dev version) is installed based on this link:

```
http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets31Binaries
```

and noticed that corresponded head files are put in:

```
/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/wx.h
```

In heard file,"wx.h" is included like this:

```
#ifndef DSTODO_H_
#define DSTODO_H_
#include <wx/wx.h>
```

when building,eclipse gives me:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
clang++ -I/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src/DSToDo.bc ../src/DSToDo.cpp 
In file included from ../src/DSToDo.cpp:8:
../src/DSToDo.h:11:10: fatal error: 'wx/wx.h' file not found
#include <wx/wx.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

After changing including to:

```
#include <wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/wx.h>
```

Eclipse gives me:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
clang++ -I/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src/DSToDo.bc ../src/DSToDo.cpp 
In file included from ../src/DSToDo.cpp:8:
In file included from ../src/DSToDo.h:11:
/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/wx.h:14:10: fatal error: 'wx/defs.h' file not found
#include "wx/defs.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
```

If add

```
/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial
```

to

```
c/c++ build->settings->LLVM Clang++->Includes
```

Eclipse gives:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
clang++ -I/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib **-I/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial** -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src/DSToDo.bc ../src/DSToDo.cpp 
In file included from ../src/DSToDo.cpp:8:
In file included from ../src/DSToDo.h:11:
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/wx.h:14:
In file included from /usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/defs.h:20:
/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/platform.h:136:10: fatal error: 'wx/setup.h' file not found
#include "wx/setup.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: what is you project settings for the "Header Search Path" and "Linker Options"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `-I/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial` to your compiler options.

I have no idea why are the headers installed in this non-standard location however.

Comment: You really need to read the [documentation](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.0/docs/msw/install.txt#L494) for building applications using wxWidgets, I really don't understand how do you expect anything to work if you hadn't done anything.